# 自動露出とオートフォーカスの切り方が分からない

Tags: android, camera

現在Android Studioでcamera2APIを用いて可視光(Li-Fi)の研究をしています。
ですがLEDを撮影しデータを取得する際にどうしても自動露出とオートフォーカスが邪魔になってしまいます。

・自動露出
・オートフォーカス

上記二つの切り方を教えてください。

**仕様**
Android Studio3.1

**スマートフォン**
SHARP AQUOS API23
HUAWEI P10 API24

Comment: マルチポスト https://qiita.com/140442066/items/adfb5e62a017853c8d9f 「マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？ - スタック・オーバーフローMeta」 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/%e3%83%9e%e3%83%ab%e3%83%81%e3%83%9d%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b-%e4%bd%95%e3%81%8b%e5%95%8f%e9%a1%8c%e3%81%8c%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b

Answer (score 1):

`CameraCaptureSession`の`capture`メソッドなどは[引数に`CameraRequest`を取ります](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession#capture(android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback,%20android.os.Handler))。`CameraRequest`には[様々なフィールドがあり](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#summary)、`CONTROL_AF_MODE`と`CONTROL_AE_MODE`がそれぞれオートフォーカスと自動露出に対応します。これらを`OFF`にセットすれば無効になります。また、ホワイトバランス調整を含めた3つをまとめて設定できる`CONTROL_MODE`も提供されています。

`CameraDevice`の[`createCaptureRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureRequest(int))を使うと、それぞれのカメラに適した`CameraRequest.Builder`を生成できるので、これを書き換えてAF等を無効にしていくのがよいでしょう。

[Googleのサンプルコード](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/71e83b90d9ce25b74970e98aaf1c26532606eb2c/Camera2Basic/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/basic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L328)を引用します（コメントは引用者によるもの）。

```kotlin
val captureRequest = session.device.createCaptureRequest(
                     CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE).apply { addTarget(imageReader.surface) }

  // ここで captureRequest.set(CONTROL_AF_MODE, OFF) などとする

session.capture(captureRequest.build(), object : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
  ...
```